# Dagger ObjectGraph plus() Modules that include modules in the root module keep returning No no-args constructor

Tags: android, dependency-injection, include, square, dagger

I have an Android app that uses Dagger. There are certain sections of the entire app that I want to add scoped ObjectGraphs for several activities that share a common scope. The following module is in the root ObjectGraph

```
@Module(
    injects = {
            MyApplication.class,
    },
    complete = false,
    library = true)
public class BasicContextManagerModule {

    private Context applicationContext;

    public BasicContextManagerModule(Context applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Provides
    Context getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Then I try to add the following Module through existingObjectGraph.plus(new FileManagerModule());

```
@Module(
    injects = {
            MyListActivity.class,
            MyFileDetailActivity.class,
            MyFileInfoActivity.class,
    },
    includes = BasicContextManagerModule.class
)
public class FileManagerModule {

    @Provides
    FileManager provideFileManager(Context context) {
        return new FileManager(context);
    }
}
```

But the result is

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No no-args constructor com.myapp.core.modules.BasicContextManagerModule$$ModuleAdapter
```

Can someone help me understand why the plus won't allow this? I read from the dagger documentation that plus extends the object graph and you can have includes and addsTo Modules. But I haven't been able to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`includes` means the module will live in the same subgraph, and Dagger will instantiate it if you don't pass an instance.

`addsTo` means the referenced module is expected to be in the graph (actually in a parent graph) but Dagger won't provide it for you.

What you want is `addsTo`.

Comment: Hey Thomas, So I did as you had suggestted and it works. But what I am wondering is the FileManagerModule addsTo the module that only provides a context, does it screw anything up with the bundings for places that only need a Context and no need for a fileManager?

Comment: No. When your subgraph needs to inject such an object, it'll get the context from the parent graph (and if the object is a singleton, it'll be scoped to the subgraph, not the parent graph)